# Django 2.2.1's runserver gives circular import error instead of showing the actual error

Tags: python, django, upgrade

I recently upgraded a project from Django 2.1.7 to 2.2.1. 
The python version in my venv is 3.6.1

After this, when I start my project on Pycharm using `manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` Django stopped telling me about **SyntaxErrors** in my code.

Instead it started giving an unrelated and incorrect message about a possible empty urls.py and suggests this might be caused by a circular import.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread: 
Traceback resolvers.py line 581, in url_patterns iter(patterns) 
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Downgrading back to Django 2.1.7 is a workaround that works. I found this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30500 that might be related but it was closed without resolving. But I'd like to know how to get correct error reporting back in Django 2.2.1, using Python 3.6.1.

Comment: It worked as expected in Python 3.6.1 and Django 2.1.7. The issue was observed after upgrading to Django 2.2.1, and went away after downgrading back to Django 2.1.7.  I have `__init__.py` in all my `/django_project/django_app` directories, but not in my `/django_project` directory